# Can't change location in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, location

I just went to [Edit Profile & Settings] and by location this is what I saw:

[image]

And if I hover over it or try to click, I get a red 'no' sign:

[image]

After reloading the page, it loads properly for a second and then does the same thing.

[image]

#### Confirmed this on multiple sites (including Meta, Graduated and Beta sites).

Comment: Same here.......

Comment: The location field uses the Google Maps API to autocomplete locations. It's currently throwing an error: "RefererNotAllowedMapError" ...basically SE need to update their API key[s]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369086/oops-something-went-wrong-in-the-location-field-on-edit-profile-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been locking down our Google API keys (in response to the Google Maps Platform announcement) and it turns out that the JS autocomplete bits need access to both the Places API and JavaScript Maps API. I'd only switched on access to the Places API because a) metrics said we weren't using it and b) when I gave it a test run there were no issues. I flipped the switch and then left for the day.

I get back this morning and it's broken. Turns out there's a lag with credential changes \o/

It's fixed now, apologies for the inconvenience.